# Jupiter Notebook loses server connection when running NUTS sampling with PyMc3

Tags: python, jupyter-notebook, anaconda, theano, pymc3

I have a problem running my Python code in JupiterNotebook. I am currently working on an statistical model using the module Pymc3 (pm). The code appears to be right but still it won't work. I built a model using pm.Model(). Afterwards I like to create a trace for this model using pm.sample. This works out at first, the process achieves a convergence and then it should begin sampling the chains.But at this point JupiterNotebook **always** immediately loses the server connection and is unable to reconnect. Then I need to completely restart JupiterNotebook to be able to reconnenct. In the picture below you can see the exact point when the problem occurs. It' s an annoying problem since I don't receive a failure. I really don't understand whats the problem or how to solve it... I have already tried reinstalling Theano and Pymc3, I' ve even reinstalled Anaconda just to make sure the compiler isn't lost in some kind of loop or so.
I would be glad if someone could help me with this please. I am still quite new to Python and JupiterNotebook, so my troubleshooting skills are limited. Looking forward to answers!

Thanks Leon

https://i.stack.imgur.com/75u3S.png

The code I am testing with:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
import pymc3 as pm

RANDOM_SEED = 8927
np.random.seed(RANDOM_SEED)

print("Running on PyMC3 v{}".format(pm.__version__))


#true parameters
alpha, sigma = 1, 1
beta = [1, 2.5]
# Size of dataset
size = 100

# Predictor variable
X1 = np.random.randn(size)
X2 = np.random.randn(size) * 0.2

# Simulate outcome variable
Y = alpha + beta[0] * X1 + beta[1] * X2 + np.random.randn(size) * sigma

with basic_model:

    # Priors for unknown model parameters
    alpha = pm.Normal("alpha", mu=0, sigma=10)
    beta = pm.Normal("beta", mu=0, sigma=10, shape=2)
    sigma = pm.HalfNormal("sigma", sigma=1)

    # Expected value of outcome
    mu = alpha + beta[0] * X1 + beta[1] * X2

    # Likelihood (sampling distribution) of observations
    Y_obs = pm.Normal("Y_obs", mu=mu, sigma=sigma, observed=Y)

with basic_model:
    # draw 500 posterior samples
    trace = pm.sample(500, init='advi',cores=2)


az.plot_trace(trace);
```

Comment: You mention some picture, but I can't see any... Maybe you could edit your question and add a code snippet instead?

Comment: Please try running some of [the very simple tutorial examples](https://docs.pymc.io/notebooks/getting_started.html) and report whether those also fail. Right now, it is unclear what is a problem with your setup/infrastructure and what is an issue with whatever custom model you are attempting to implement.

Comment: First of all thanks for your quick replies! Seems like the imgur link wasn't visible before, you should know be able to see a screenshot of the problem. I have also tried a really simple example, but still it won't work. I will add the code to my post above. Everything is working fine just until the program should sample the chains: Server-connection gets lost and that's it, nothing moves from there on.

Comment: That last line of inference in the picture I sent (Sampling 2 chains, 0 divergences:   0%|          | 0/2000 [00:00<?, ?draws/s]) is the exact point when the server connection gets lost. I do not understand how it happens. The code runs without problems to this point (slow but it works) and then always at this point without a tracable reason the kernel gets disconnected.

Comment: does it work with one core: pm.sample(500, init='advi',cores=1)?

Comment: @balleveryday yes that works! For such a simple model that's totally fine but if you work with complex data and models I think it might get hard only using one core... I tried some things today and it appears to be a problem using init='advi', cause on default settings it also works. Do you know what's causing the problems using init='advi'?